# How to modify SQL query to get latest date

Tags: sql, prestashop

I need to obtain the latest order date in `statsbestproducts` module, I added it to the SQL query but I obtain the first order date (between two dates). How to change it for latest dates? And also how to remove the time from this date?

[image: screen]

Comment: Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the [Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
... MIN(o.date_add) AS `date` ...
```